# How to plot arbitrarily many subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I usually do this when I want to make 2 plots:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

What if I have multiple lists of images and want to run the same function on each list so that every image in that list is plotted? Each list has a different number of images.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
num_subplots = len(listoffigs)
axs = []
for i in range(num_subplots):
    axs.append(plt.subplot(num_subplots, 1, i+1))
```

or even shorter, as list comprehension:

```
num_subplots = len(listoffigs)
axs = [plt.subplot(num_subplots, 1, i+1) for i in range(num_subplots)]
```

*) edit: Added list comprehension solution

Comment: the list comprehension solution is the one i've been looking for, actually quite a bit faster than other suggestions in similar questions

Comment: but how to use the list then as a figure?

Comment: You get the different subplots from their list indexes. Thus `axs[0]` will reference the first subplot.

Answer (score 1):

First there is no difference between having several lists or one long list, so merge all lists into one

```
biglist = list1 + list2 + list3
```

Then you can determine the number of subplots needed from the length of the list. In the simplest case make a square grid,

```
n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(len(biglist))))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n,n)
```

Fill the grid with your images,

```
for i, image in enumerate(biglist):
    axes.flatten()[i].imshow(image)
```

For the rest of the axes turn the spines off

```
while i < n*n:
    axes.flatten()[i].axis("off")
    i += 1
```